# Selecting features and saving selection as shapefile using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis

For some reason my code is not doing what I expect it to do.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface
import processing

# Load the layer
layer = iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()

bluespaces = QgsExpression ( " \"ITEM2012\" = 'Wetlands' OR \"ITEM2012\" = 'Water'")
selection = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(bluespaces))
ids = ([k.id() for k in selection])
layer.setSelectedFeatures( ids )
newlayer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, 
               'U:\PythonTest\bluespaces.shp', 'System', 
               QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(25382), 'ESRI Shapefile', bool(True))
```

This should give me a shapefile containing the blue spaces from the input layer. It works fine with other selection criteria and I checked if something was wrong with the selection criteria used above numerous times, but to no avail.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Okay, I figured out that it has something to do with the first letter. When I safe it as "zluespaces", it works fine. Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `\b` is a special character for backspace. That's why. You should use a raw string (`r` in front of the path name) in this case.

```
newlayer =  QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, 
                r'U:\PythonTest\bluespaces.shp', 'System', 
                QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(25382), 'ESRI Shapefile', bool(True))
```

The computer recognizes the special characters instead of the path, example
`"C:\newFolder"` is not correct because `\n` is the special character for a new line (enter). To tell that you want the string as it is you have to use the `r` in front of the path name.